# Python: Splitting a long string by character for input into dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, python-2.7

I am importing a file into a dictionary. The file is organized with lines like this:

```
Category One?Category Two?Category Three?Category 4?Category 5
```

I'm splitting each line into its individual categories with the intention that the information contained in Category One and Category Two need to be combined into a single category to eventually be the key, whereas the rest of the categories contain information that's later going to be values.

I haven't worked with this many categories before (I've done Cat1 = key and Cat2 = value) so I'm a little confused about how to apply what I know.

Assuming I'd already collected and opened the source file, if I had only two categories, I would do:

```
dict1 = {}
for line in file:
    k,v = line.split('?')
    dict1[k.strip()] = v.strip()
```

I'm not sure how to combine the data in the Category One and Category Two spots into functionally one category, nor how to collect categories 3-5 into separate values. Right now I'm just focusing on splitting them into Category One = key and Categories Everything Else = values. It doesn't seem that changing line 3 to k,v,v,v,v really works, more's the pity; this produces

```
{'Category One': 'Category Five')
```

Am I missing something obvious? **Edit** Yes I sure was- and boy, do I need another cup of coffee this morning. Of course if I call everything v it will just give me the last thing I called v...

(Obviously my source file looks different from this, but the basic organization is the same.)

Comment: I'm confused.  Based on your line above, what entries are supposed to be the keys and what are the associated values?

Answer (score 2):

maybe something like:

```
dict1 = {}
for line in file:
    x = line.strip().split('?')
    dict1[(x[0],x[1])] = x[2:]
```

would do what you want. You need to convert the values into something hashable first though.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
l = line.split('?')
d = dict([(k, v) for k,v in zip (l[::2], l[1::2])])
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like you want something like:

```
for line in file:
    k,v = line.split('?',1)
    dict1[k.strip()] = [x.strip() for x in v.split('?')]
```

It might be a little cleaner to do something like:

```
for line in file:
    lsplit = [x.strip() for x in line.split('?')]
    dict1[lsplit[0]] = lsplit[1:]
```

In the case where you didn't need to do any stripping, you could use `operator.itemgetter`:

```
splitter = itemgetter(0,slice(1,None))
dict(splitter(x.split('?')) for x in file))
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure I understand what you need, but seems to me you want something like this:

```
wordsInLine = line.split( '?' )
key = wordsInLine[ 0 ], wordsInLine[ 1 ]    # first two are used as a key
value = wordsInLine[ 2: ]  # the rest are the 'value'
dictionary[ key ] = value
```

the key is actualy a tuple with two values in it. You can access a value like this:

```
dictionary[ ( x, y ) ]
```

hope this helps